# Jersey client Internal server error post call

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

```
public String makePostCall(String url, String username, String password
       ) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        KeyManagementException, URISyntaxException {

    target = (WebTarget) getClientInstance().target(new URI(url));
    Map<String,String> input=new HashMap<String,String>();
    input.put("name","foo");
 Response   response = target.request("application/json")
         .post(Entity.entity(input,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
return response.readEntity(String.class);
}
```

Comment: What is Exception you get?

Comment: Internal server error